# como obtener datos de un formulario MDI desde un modal en c#

Tags: c#

Hola a toda la comunidad, Tengo el siguiente problema:
Tengo Un Formulario principal (DesktopMain...asi lo he llamado), desde ese formulario llamo a un formulario hijo llamado ClienteList. En este formulario llamo a otro de forma modal(ShowDialog) llamado ClienteDetail. Este se encarga de registrar un nuevo cliente en la bd...el problema está en que necesito obtener un dato del formulario principal(DesktopMain) para poder guardarlo en la BD...el dato que trato de obtener es el IdUsuario que crea el nuevo registro, pero como llego hasta ese dato desde la ventana modal.
Esa variable esta declarada como  pero aun asi no llego a obtener su valor...espero me puedan ayudar...gracias

Comment: Hola, porfavor pon lo que tienes hecho hasta ahora para poderte ayudar, te espero

Answer (score 0):

En el DesktopMain expon el valor de la variable como una propiedad pública, así podrás verla desde el otro formulario.